# How does Rediff calculate MVPI (Most valuable player index) for IPL?

Tags: cricket, ranking, indian-premier-league

I have come across a lot of Rediff articles, where they give MVPI rankings. Before a series, after a series, IPL etc. How do they calculate this? What is the formula? What are parameters of the formula?

Answer (score 1):

[Check for the source](http://www.rediff.com/cricket/report/indias-most-valuable-odi-players-this-year/20180221.htm)

The Most Valuable Player Index (MVPI) picks out batsmen who score a lot of runs at a high strike rate, bowlers who take a lot of wickets at a low economy rate, and fielders who take the most catches or participate in run outs.

MVPI expresses a player's overall batting + bowling + fielding performance in terms of a 'run equivalent'.

MVPI: Most Valuable Player Index = Sum of batting, bowling and fielding points. Run outs are counted as 1 (wicket) for a direct hit, and 0.5 (wicket) if the fielder is an equal participant in a run out dismissal.